# Отправка сообщения на e-mail Exchange

Tags: zabbix, bash, exchange

Есть сервер `Exchange 2010`. Создано правило транспорта, что при поступлении  писем на один почтовый ящик автоматически рассылать в копиях и на другие.

Все работает, но тут я захотел через заббикс отправлять `email` оповещения на этот адрес, чтобы он ещё всем другим рассылал, и оно не работает. Если я отправляю с самой почты `error@domain.ru` на `trans@domain.ru`, то правило срабатывает. Если же автоматически с авторизацией через `error`, то приходит только на `trans`.

Почему не идет дальше на копии? Как это устранить?

```
export smtpemailfrom="error@domain.ru"

SUBJECT=$(echo $2 | iconv -f UTF-8 -t KOI8-R//IGNORE)
BODY=$(echo $3 | iconv -f UTF-8 -t KOI8-R//IGNORE)

export zabbixemailto="$1"

export smtpserver=domain.ru

export smtplogin=error

export smtppass=lKJldhg564tqpLp


echo "" >> /var/log/zabbix/send_email.log

date >> /var/log/zabbix/send_email.log

echo "/usr/bin/sendEmail -f "$smtpemailfrom" -t "$zabbixemailto" -u "$SUBJECT" -m "$BODY" -s $smtpserver:25 -xu $smtplogin -xp $smtppass -o message-charset=CP1251".
>> /var/log/zabbix/send_email.log

/usr/bin/sendEmail -f "$smtpemailfrom" -t "$zabbixemailto" -u "$SUBJECT" -m "$BODY" -s $smtpserver:25 -xu $smtplogin -xp $smtppass -o message-charset=KOI8-R.
>> /var/log/zabbix/send_email.log 2>> /var/log/zabbix/send_email.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю Вам лучше всего делать не правило на `Exchnage`, а группу рассылки. Правило всегда нагружает систему и больше вероятности допустить ошибку. В то время как группой рассылки проще управлять, не говоря о том, что они предназначены для этого.

В крайнем случае в правилах самого почтового ящика настроить переадресацию писем по правилу. Но не на уровне сервера `Exchange`.